# RRD works not from shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, rrdtool, rrd

I am using this code to create a graph with the the RRD:

```
#!/bin/sh
rrdtool graph tempweek.png \
-s "now - 1 day" -e "now" \
DEF:temp0=temperature.rrd:temp0:AVERAGE \
LINE2:temp0#33E500:Außen \
DEF:temp1=temperature.rrd:temp1:AVERAGE \
LINE2:temp1#FF6600:Pool \
DEF:temp2=temperature.rrd:temp2:AVERAGE \
LINE2:temp2#0066CC:Dach
```

When I insert the command in the console all works finde but when I run it via a shell script I got an error.

[image]

Comment: Including the error message(s) would help considerably in understanding what the problem is...

Comment: The line continuations are invalid (is there whitespace after `\ `? `\ ` should be the last character on the line). Worst case, put everything on one line.

Comment: I got the same error when i write all commands in one line and remove the \

Comment: I doubt you are getting the exact same error. The other thing is that `#` is the shell comment character, you'll need to escape it or put the arguments `DEF...` and `LINE...` in quotes.

Comment: You are right, When I write all in one line it works. I forget to remove one \

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you used a windows editor to write your script ... it inserts CRLF between lines instead of just LF as it is the norm in Unixland.

This little perl one-liner ...

```
perl -I~ -pe 's/\r\n/\n/g' rrd.sh
```

will fix your script. Run it on the command line.

To stop this from happening in the future make sure to set your editor
to write files with LF line endings.